# PHP is Not Sending Email Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, email

I am trying to send email with php using AJAX. When I click the button nothing happens. No error and no mail in my mailbox. Here is my code:

index.php:

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4"> 
        <center>
            <form method="post">
               <section id="left">
                  <label for="form_email">Email</label>
                  <input name="form_email" id="form_email" type="email" >
               </section>
               <section id="right">
                  <label for="form_msg">Message</label>
                  <textarea name="form_msg" id="form_msg"></textarea>
                  <button id="submit" class="button" name="submit" type="button">Send</button>
               </section>
            </form> 
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is javascript in index.php:

```
<script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
    var data = {
    email: $("#form_email").val(),
    message: $("#form_msg").val(),
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
    }
    });
        });
</script>
```

External mail.php:

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['form_email'];
    $subject = "AdrTürkiye Veri Giriş Ekranı";
    $message = $_POST['form_msg'];

    @mail($email, $subject, $message);   
?>
```

Comment: Check the console for errors in the JS, and do some basic troubleshooting in the PHP (like `var_dump($_POST);`). Suppressing `@` the mail-errors isn't going to help either. Might also want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail

Comment: there is no error in console

Comment: your mail code is wrong in mail.php

Comment: what is the correct one? aman

Comment: For sending mails, you should consider using [PHPMailer](http://github.com/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0):

jscript

```
 <script>
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  
            url: "mail.php",
            data:  $('#mailForm').serializeArray(),
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

mail.php

```
<?php
    $email = $_POST['form_email'];
    $subject = "AdrTürkiye Veri Giriş Ekranı";
    $message = $_POST['form_msg'];
    $status = @mail($email, $subject, $message); 
    if ($status == 1) {
        echo 1;
    }
    else {
        echo 0;
    }

?>
```

Comment: form a give an id and serializeArray function use